# How to reduce the spacing between text lines in the same mat-option?

Tags: html, css, angular

[image: drop down description]

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel mat-option.mat-option {
  height: unset;
}

::ng-deep .mat-option-text.mat-option-text {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Right now I'm using these set of code so that the text in options wraps up to next line if it's too long to get displayed in a single line.
The issue is there is a white space between the text lines within the mat options that wraps down.(As shown in the image). I want to reduce the line spacing within the same mat option.  Please suggest your solutions, thank you.

Comment: Look in the inspector to find out what takes up the space. It can be padding, margin, line-height, border or even a flexbox spacing the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `line-height`

**Here are some examples (Run code snippet to see):**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.one {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.two {
  border: 1px solid;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.three {
  border: 1px solid;
  line-height: 5px;
}

.four {
  border: 1px solid;
  line-height: 0px;
}

.five {
  border: 1px solid;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one box">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
  <p>Normal line height</p>
</div>

<div class="two box">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
  <p>30px line height</p>
</div>

<div class="three box">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
  <p>5px line height</p>
</div>

<div class="four box">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
  <p>0px line height</p>
</div>

<div class="five box">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
  <p>50px line height</p>
</div>
```